# Pasar parámetros a otra clase Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

necesito pasar el parámetro EditTextCarrer y que el resultado de este lo implante en el ValorCarrer.

Tengo echo el programa y no me da error pero aún así no me hace el cambio.. Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

el MAIN. ( Aquí es donde esta ValorCarrer ) ( He quitado partes del programa que no se necesitan para esta parte )

```
package com.example.eac1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EAC1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText texto; // Creamos la variable texto que utilizaremos en el editText.
    TextView NomFinal;// Nom que sortira quan ompli l'usuari.
    TextView Adreça1, Carrer1, CP1, Poblacio1, DadesP, Telefon1, Web1; // Creem variables de les dades a demanar
    TextView ValorCarrer, ValorCP, ValorP, ValorT, ValorW; // Creem variables de les dades a omplir
    TextView ButtonMasInvi, ButtonResetInvi, TextNomInvi; // Creem variables dels buttons y el TextNom a esborrar.
    TextView ButtonEnvia, ButtonLlap, ButtonX, ButtonTlf, ButtonUl; // Buttons nous.
    TextView telf, web, Carrer, CP, Poblacio; // ens serviran per verificar si envia es ple.
    EditText EditCarrer, EditTlf, EditWeb, EditCp, EditPoblacio; // aquests els ultilitzarem per lúltima pantalla

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
        // Inicializamos el EditText, básicamente lo pasamos a la variable texto para poder utilizarlo.
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextNom);
        NomFinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NomCognoms);
        telf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Valortelf);
        web =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValorWeb);
        Carrer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ValorCarrer);
        CP = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ValorCodiPostal);
        Poblacio =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ValorPoblacio);
        EditCarrer =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextCarrer);
        EditTlf =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextTelf);
        EditWeb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextWeb);
        EditCp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextCP);
        EditPoblacio =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextPoblacio);

    }
    // Ahora vamos hacer el TEXTVIEW. Este programa detectara si el texto esta vacío o no.
    public void TextAcceptat(View vista) {
        // primero pasamos el texto a String para poder analizarlo.
        String textoFin = texto.getText().toString();
        if (textoFin.isEmpty()) { // Si el texto esta vacío..
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Heu d'escriure quelcom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        } else { // Sino el resto del programa
            // Primero modificamos el textView para que muestre  el nombre
            NomFinal.setText(textoFin); // Transformem el viewText en el text que ha introduït l'usuari
            // Cridem el métode
            MostraryOcultarBotones();
        }}

    public void MostraryOcultarBotones (){

        // Empezamos hacer visibles el resto de cosas:
        Adreça1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Adreça);
        Adreça1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Carrer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Carrer);
        Carrer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Ahora de los valores del telefono etc..
        ValorCarrer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValorCarrer);
        ValorCarrer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValorCP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValorCodiPostal);
        ValorCP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValorP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValorPoblacio);
      }

    public void PasarPagina(View vista) {
        //El que farem es que el boto Llapis cuan apretem pasi a una altre pàgina
           Intent intent = new Intent(EAC1.this, DadesPersonals.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 11);
        }

        // Aquest metode ens permet tornar aquesta finestra.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Ls info la vaig buscar a google.
        if (requestCode == 11) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                boolean VolverAtras= data.getBooleanExtra("desbloquear_boton", false);
                // Aqui podem afegir els canvis que introdueix l'usuari.
                String ValorCarrer =data.getStringExtra("ValorCarrer");

                if(VolverAtras) {
                    // Es debloqueja el button.
                }

            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // la resposta es cancelada.
            }
        }
    }//

    public void TornarInici(View vista) {
        //El que farem es que al apretar la X tornarem al menú inicial.
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
        Intent intent= new Intent (EAC1.this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void Trucar(View vista) {
        // primero pasamos el texto a String para poder analizarlo.
        String textoTelf = telf.getText().toString();
        if (textoTelf == "Valor no definit" || textoTelf.equalsIgnoreCase("Valor no definit") || textoTelf.isEmpty()) { // Si el texto esta vacío..
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El camp ''Telefon'' està buït!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show(); // en aquest cas mostrare sempre que hi estigui el valor no definit i empty podría fer apart
            // verificacions per veure si conté 9 números etc.. Si hem dona temps pulire aquestes coses.
        } else { // Funcion llamar.
            String textoTelfFinal = telf.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(textoTelfFinal));
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

Y aquí la otra pantalla donde esta el EditTextCarrer.

```
package com.example.eac1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class DadesPersonals extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dades_personals);
    }

    public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        //Amb aquest boto el que aconseguim es tornar enrere.
        Intent resultado = new Intent();
        // aqui especificamos los datos que queremos enviar la primera
        resultado.putExtra("desbloquear_boton", true);
        resultado.putExtra("ValorCarrer", "EditTextCarrer");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultado);
        finish();
     }

    public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
        //Tornem a la pantalla inicial.
        Intent intent= new Intent (DadesPersonals.this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

A modo resumen la página2 que es DADESPERSONALES me devuelve a EAC1, pero me devuelve a esa página mostrando botones ocultos.

gracias

Comment: quieres que la segunda activity mande parámetros a la ya abierta?

Comment: no entiendo por abierta... 

Quiero que al apretar el boton aceptar aparte de mostrarme los botones, me cambie el titulo de un EditText..

Comment: Estas pasando un texto y no el valor del EditText. **resultado.putExtra("ValorCarrer", "EditTextCarrer");** Coloca una variable en lugar de **"EditTextCarrer"** **resultado.putExtra("ValorCarrer", miVariable);**

Comment: También puedes probar con **String ValorCarrer = getIntent().getStringExtra("ValorCarrer");** para recibirlo.

Comment: he hecho lo que me dices pero no se muestra el cambio. Sigue igual que antes.. T_T

Comment: Ahora mismo mi programa no pasa nada, ni valor ni texto ni nada. Me falta algo y no sé que es.